# How to omit NA in a subset of variables but where other variables are still present?

Tags: r

there are 8 tests and numerous demographic variables. I want to omit those who dont have complete test data, and compare demographics with the original dataset to see if there is selection bias. which I will do with chi-square.

I already tried na.omit and only ended up with a new data frame of the 8 variables.

```
dput(head(df))
structure(list(ï..leerlingnr2013 = 10048001:10048006, schoolnr = c(1004L, 
1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L), toets_ws = c(78, 91, 75, 
98, 79, 92), toets_dmt = c(103, 97, 112, 98, 71, 112), toets_bl = c(35, 
57, 55, 63, 15, 46), toets_rw = c(109, 100, 115, 113, 92, 99), 
    citotaal = c(72L, 81L, 81L, 82L, 61L, 85L), citorekwisk = c(50L, 
    49L, 49L, 42L, 40L, 46L), citostudiev = c(31L, 36L, 35L, 
    34L, 31L, 34L), citowereld = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), gebmaand = c(6L, 
    6L, 3L, 6L, 7L, 1L), gebjaar = c(2001L, 2002L, 2002L, 2001L, 
    2001L, 2002L), geslacht = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), oplei_vader = c(3L, 
    3L, 3L, NA, 2L, NA), oplei_moeder = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
    2L), CoolSES = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 2L), zorgleerling = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), welblk = c(3.71428571428571, 3.71428571428571, 
    4.28571428571429, 3.71428571428571, 3.71428571428571, 3.42857142857143
    ), welbmll = c(3.66666666666667, 3.66666666666667, 3.83333333333333, 
    2.83333333333333, 2.66666666666667, 4.16666666666667), zelfvertr = c(4.16666666666667, 
    2.16666666666667, 3.66666666666667, 4.16666666666667, 3, 
    3.66666666666667), taak = c(3.8, 3.8, 4.6, 4.6, 4.2, 3.4), 
    bekwaming = c(3.77777777777778, 3.44444444444444, 4.11111111111111, 
    4.66666666666667, 3, 3.33333333333333), extrinsiek = c(3, 
    2.66666666666667, 3.66666666666667, 3.44444444444444, 2.11111111111111, 
    3.33333333333333), prestatie = c(2.57142857142857, 3.85714285714286, 
    3.28571428571429, 1.57142857142857, 1.71428571428571, 2.28571428571429
    ), sociaal = c(3.57142857142857, 2.57142857142857, 3.42857142857143, 
    3.57142857142857, 3.28571428571429, 3.28571428571429)), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Please add a sample of your data with `dput(head(df,n))`. Are you looking for `df[complete.cases(df),]`?

Comment: Tweaking NelsonGon's code `df[complete.cases(df[subsetColNames]),]` if you want to check for subset of columns

Comment: test = df[complete.cases(df[,3:10]),]  This did it. 10 points to house Ravenclaw.